# Decrement QTimer

Tags: qt, qtimer

I have a QTimer and when I click on an object I want to decrement this QTimer. For that, I use the start function which allows, if the timer is launched, to stop it and restart it with the value passed in parameter. My function is called but as long as the timer has not reached a value close to 4100 the time is not decremented. Once the 4100 is reached (around) it works fine, does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work when the remaining time is too high?

testclick.h :

```
#ifndef TESTCLICK_H
#define TESTCLICK_H

#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QDebug>

class TestClick : public QWidget
{
private :
    QTimer* timer;

public:
    TestClick();
    ~TestClick();

    void mousePressEvent (QMouseEvent* event);
};

#endif // TESTCLICK_H
```

testclick.cpp :

```
#include "testclick.h"

TestClick::TestClick()
{
    timer = new QTimer();
    timer->start(8000);
}

TestClick::~TestClick()
{
    delete timer;
}

void TestClick::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug()<<"before remainingTime :"<<timer->remainingTime();
    timer->start(timer->remainingTime() - 200);
    qDebug()<<"after remainingTime :"<<timer->remainingTime();
}
```

main.cpp :

```
#include "testclick.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    TestClick test;
    test.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

And I have :

```
before remainingTime : 5260
after remainingTime : 5260
before remainingTime : 4908
after remainingTime : 4908
before remainingTime : 4780
after remainingTime : 4780
before remainingTime : 4660
after remainingTime : 4660
before remainingTime : 4508
after remainingTime : 4508
before remainingTime : 4348
after remainingTime : 4348
before remainingTime : 4196
after remainingTime : 3996
before remainingTime : 3836
after remainingTime : 3636
before remainingTime : 3476
after remainingTime : 3276
before remainingTime : 3116
after remainingTime : 2916
before remainingTime : 2740
after remainingTime : 2540
before remainingTime : 2380
after remainingTime : 2180
before remainingTime : 2012
```

I use Qt5 and Debian.

Comment: Please edit your question to provide a [mcve] and clarify what you mean by `decrement this QTimer`.

Comment: You'll have to provide some minimal example code. I can't reproduce it. Start with a single `main.cpp` file: `#include <QtCore>` `int main(int argc, char **argv) { QCoreApplication app(argc, argv); QTimer timer; /* add stuff here */ return app->exec(); }`

Comment: "Decrementing" a `QTimer` means making the timer timeout sooner than expected. Is that waht you meant. You might be blocking somewhere in your code - recall that timer timeout signals are *only* emitted when the control is within `QCoreApplication::exec`, not within your own code. If your code blocks anywhere, i.e. waits for stuff without returning to `exec`, that's the problem. How will you know? Very easily: pause your program when "wrong" things happen, and check whether any of your own code is on the call stack *above* `exec`: in an average case, it shouldn't be.

Comment: I ran your code directly and it works correctly for me. I used Qt 5.12.3 with MSVC 2017 windows 10. I wonder if the stop then start of the timer takes some time to process so when you are printing the `after` debug statement, it might still be grabbing the timer object as it's in a pending state and so just uses it's last known remaining time.

Comment: I try with Qt::PreciseTimer and it's work fine. Thanks for your help !